Is there any way to replace integers with tensors in torch?
Say I have
a = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[2,1,3]])
And i want to replace integers 1,2,3 with [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] respectively.
Meaning,
i want
result = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8,9]])
Of course for me these tensors are a bit larger so i want to do this effectively.
How can i do this with minimal computational effort?
I have tried numpy vectorize but you need to change the signature and apparently it makes it slower.
I failed to use torch.vmap as it doesnt let you use .item() within the vmap

How about simple indexing?
In [281]: x = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,1,3]])    
In [282]: y = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])    
In [283]: x,y
Out[283]: 
(array([[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 1, 3]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]))

Assuming the 1,2,3 of x correspond to 'indicies' of y rows (adjusted for 0 base), we can use simple indexing:
In [284]: y[x-1,:]
Out[284]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[4, 5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [7, 8, 9]]])

And to get the 2d array you want, just reshape:
In [285]: y[x-1,:].reshape(2,-1)
Out[285]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]])

